# how to insert gap between rows of a table?

Tags: html, css, django

i want to add gap betweenw my input boxes in input form.
They are heavily packed together and not looking good.
so that the input form looks and feels good...form is a object passed from views.py....

createcustomer.html

```
 {% extends 'customer/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}Create Customer{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; width:100%; height:135%;" >
        <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-left" align="center">
            <h2>Create a Customer</h2>
        <form action="." method="post">
            <div class="form-group" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <tr style="width:100%;" class="highlight">
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>{{form.fname}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td>{{form.lname}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>{{form.email}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address:</td>
                    <td>{{form.address}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td>{{form.city}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>State:</td>
                    <td>{{form.state}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zip:</td>
                    <td>{{form.zip}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td>{{form.uname}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td>{{form.phone}}</td>
                </tr>
               </table>
            <div style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
            </div></div>
        </form>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    {%endblock%}
```

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap, you should just use the `form-control` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with css:

```
table tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add table to `cellspacing` & `cellpadding`

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply padding to the input itself by applying a class and css:

HTML

```
<input id="padded" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
```

CSS

```
#padded { 
padding: 10px;
}
```

This will create space around the input form, giving it room to breath.